# Google-like search box with an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-form

I am writing an application which UI wise is almost exactly like Google. I arrive at landing page I have a search box which on submit directs you to results page. Here you have the same search box and other directives in which you can switch between modes: eg. web, image.
Currently I have:

on landing page: form with action="results.html" which passes the parameters in the url.

```
<form name="search" role="form" action="results.html">
    <div class="input-group input-group-search">

        <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="blab" name="q" required>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <button class="btn-search" ng-disabled="search.$invalid">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="web"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

on results I am just using ng-submit="search()" and ng-model on the input. The search box is within the searchController.

What is the right method for doing this as a custom directive, with the following behaviour:

- On landing page on submit direct to results page
- On results page make a search without reloading the page and change the location to the right parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run something similar on my site currently. I however did not wrap my search into a directive because it is it's own page.

For how I have it setup, I have a search page `site.com/search` (which would be your landing page for example) That page has its own controller/view `SearchController`. On the same page lies a separate container which can essentially list items that are inside an array. Finally, the entire page has an `ApplicationController`.

Now, the `SearchController` and `ApplicationController` are obviously separate and therefore cannot access each-other's properties or methods. What they can do however, is either share a factory/service or broadcast information. For the simplicity of this example we will have them share a service called `SearchService`.

If you still wish to use a directive, you can easily turn the `SearchController` into a directive and utilize the same concept for yourself.

[Basic Plunkr Example Here](http://embed.plnkr.co/yvcKfUnz05wZT8oQfnDr/preview)

---

**SearchService**

The `SearchService` will contain useful properties and methods for searching, but all you need right now is just a simple `Array` to contain a list of search results.

```
myApp.factory('SearchService', function() {
    var SearchService;
    SearchService = {};

    // The array that will contain search results
    SearchService.arrSearchResults = [];

    return SearchService;
  }
);
```

---

**ApplicationController**

The `ApplicationController` scope will have a reference to `SearchService` so that you can use `ng-repeat` and list out the actual contents of the search results.

```
myApp.controller('ApplicationController', [
  '$scope', 'SearchService', function($scope, SearchService) {

      // Create a reference to the SearchService and add it to the 
      // $scope so it will be available on the page
      $scope.searchService = SearchService;

  }
]);
```

---

**SearchController**

The `SearchController` scope will also have a reference to `SearchService` so that it can modify the `SearchService.arrSearchResults` array, thus altering what will be displayed on the page. It will also contain methods to interact with the form.

It will also alter the URL location when a search is executed.

```
myApp.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', 'SearchService', '$http', '$location', function($scope, SearchService, $http, $location) {

    // Your search input
    $scope.blab = "";

    // Your search function
    $scope.search = function() {

    // Make sure blab has content (always good to double check)
    if($scope.blab != "") {

        // Alter URL to show new request
        $location.search('q', $scope.blab);

        // Make a GET request to your URL that will 
        // return data for you to populate
        $http.get('/someUrl').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available

                alert("Search results found!");

                // Assuming the data returned is a list of items
                // or object items
                // (i.e. [ "Search Result1", "Search Result2", ... ]
                SearchService.arrSearchResults = data;

            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.

                alert("Something failed! No results found!");

                // Empty the array of search results 
                // to show no results
                SearchService.arrSearchResults = [];
            });
    };
}]);
```

---

**The Page**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Search Example Page</title>

    <!-- Insert Angular.JS source files here -->
</head>
<body ng-controller="ApplicationController" ng-app="myApp">

    <!-- ngView -->
    <div role="main" data-ng-view>

    </div>

    <!-- Search Results -->
    <div ng-repeat="searchItem in searchService.arrSearchResults">

        <p style="border-bottom: 2px solid #000">Search Result: <br/>{{searchItem}}</p>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Tabs**

For switching the type of search result (web, image, etc) you can create a variable within the `SearchService` that controls the state of the search, and thus what type of search to run.

`SearchService.typeOfSearch = "web";` This sets the state to `web` and thus can be interacted within the page and app.

You can then have various `ng-repeat` throughout the page all showing results for different states:

```
<!-- Search Results - Web -->
<div ng-if="searchService.typeOfSearch='web'" ng-repeat="searchItem in searchService.arrSearchResults">

    <p style="border-bottom: 2px solid blue">Search Result: <br/>{{searchItem}}</p>

</div>


<!-- Search Results - Image -->
<div ng-if="searchService.typeOfSearch='image'" ng-repeat="searchItem in searchService.arrSearchResults">

    <p style="border-bottom: 2px solid red">Search Result: <br/>{{searchItem}}</p>

</div>
```

I have updated the Plunkr to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about this way: search <- service -> view. What about the tabs? Currently I have them having an ng-include for each, since the way I display them defers each time, however this means no page reload. My server call for search has just a "mode" parameter.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please select it. As far as tabs go (going to web search, image search, etc...) You can essentially have a set state in the `ApplicationController` which can be changed by your app. That state can then load different results for your searches. I'll adjust my answer to show an example...

Comment: @ManBearPixel, i have very similar requirement for my project. Here i did not understand where on-change event is handled for search text? also from where suggestions are populating. Can please ellobrate on it.

Comment: Hey @DeveshAgrawal as far as the on-change event firing from the search text input I don't think I have that implemented here, but there are two ways to go about it. 

**$scope.$watch**
You can use the `scope` to listen to changes to a variable, in this case it would be `$scope.$watch('q', function(newVal, oldVal) { ... });` 
[AngularJS Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

**ng-change**
The other way to watch for text input changes would be to use ng-change="aScopeFunc()"
[AngularJS ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal The suggestions are populated when the user hits the _Search_ button which, depending on the search state, will either grab the results from `results-web.json` or `results-image.json`. The Plunkr example doesn't have any logic to apply the search term to the actual search as this is just an example of demonstration, but ideally you would have a back-end service setup to run a query based on the search term and return back a JSON Object with the appropriate results. Hope this helps you Devesh!