# How data is filling when user start typing in search field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a search box like Google for my web page:

[image]

I came across this question: [Google-like search box with an AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28505183/google-like-search-box-with-an-angularjs-directive)

In the accepted solution, I'm not able to understand how (from where) data is populating as soon as user start typing in search text box. also where the on-change event is handled for textbox.

Can please anyone help me with this?

Comment: Data gets populated from the Json file that is being provided in the plunker.This is the one   if (SearchService.typeOfSearch == "web") {
        requestUrl = "results-web.json";
      }
      else if (SearchService.typeOfSearch == "image") {
        requestUrl = "results-image.json";
      }

Comment: @Reena, you sure about that. When you type 'a' you get almonds as suggestion. there is no almonds present in results-web.json. its only [
  "item1",
  "item2",
  "item3",
  "item4",
  "item5"
] My doubt is from where almonds is coming?

Comment: Whiel doing search I'm getting Search Result: item1, Search Result: item2 so on....... I didn't get any other value. R u talking about the plunker provided in that link Wright???

Comment: dont press search button, just type 'a' and wait.

Comment: Sorry still didn't get can you plz provide the screen shot Now I'm also curios to know about it

Comment: added. u can check now

Comment: It's pre-filling from your browser's form-fill history. You've typed "almonds" into a text field with name "q" before.

Comment: Sorry to say but this is not the search result..It is the browser functionality

Comment: You might have used this value and this value was retain as you get almonds, here in my case I'm getting angularjs...

Answer (score 0):

See this, you will get the idea that it was not the search result.

It will search only on the click of the button as per the functionality provided in the plunker, and it will be searched from the Json file only
[image]